# Why bridging wifi to vEthernet for hyper v doesnt work?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I really can't understand how networking works, it's frustrating.

So basically I understand that I can do this:

- WIFI ----- BRIDGE ---- vEthernet (external)

This should allow my vEthernet, therefore my hyper v vm to connect to my wifi... but no internet inside. It says the cable is not connected.

I selected my WIFI and the vEthernet (external), and right clicked and "Bridge connections". Then I get "An unexepcted error occurred while configuring the network bridge", but the bridge gets created.

Now my question is, how to visualize the bridges? like what is connected to what?  I went to details of the bridge and I see:

[image]

The only checked on is WIFI. What does it even mean? bridge to wifi only?

Now I check the vEthernet

[image]

and I save. Now it should be connected?

But still doesn't work. My hyper v vm is also connected to the same network:

[image]

Edit:

So after that I created a new network external 2 and added to the bridge:

wifi ---- bridge --- external 2 ---- external 1

But I disabled the WIFI... and guess what it still can connect to the internet. This means that somehow the external 2 network can connect to my ethernet, but where who defines this and where can I check what networks are linked to what networks?

Comment: Why are you using a bridge?  You don't need that for Hyper-V to share networking.

Comment: so what is the best way to do without bridge? My hyper v cant connect to internet in any other setting config. Can you share some config?